# What is the purpose of the public_hash in Magento 2 payment vault?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment

The **new integrated Vault interface** for **Magento 2 payment methods** includes a `public_hash` that is generated from the payment method information:

```
    $hashKey = $paymentToken->getGatewayToken();
    if ($paymentToken->getCustomerId()) {
        $hashKey = $paymentToken->getCustomerId();
    }

    $hashKey .= $paymentToken->getPaymentMethodCode()
        . $paymentToken->getType()
        . $paymentToken->getTokenDetails();
```

However, it is unclear to me what the purpose is of this hash. It doesn't hash any information that's not also stored in clear text, and it's not the primary key of the database table.

Does anybody know why this field was added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `public_hash` is used to reference the card from untrusted sources (like on checkout). It gives each card a unique non-sequential identifier that can't be readily guessed, to help curb any possible abuse.

Comment: What is the reason for using this instead of the entity ID of the record in the vault? If it's just an arbitrary identifier, I can't see the point. What's also strange is that it seems to be using symmetrical encryption rather than a true one-way hash, even though it's never decrypted that I can see.

Comment: I just reread your answer and noticed your point about it being "non-sequential." That explains why they don't just use the `entity_id`. Good point!